# Unskilled jobs with visa sponsorship

Tags: job-offer

Please what are the countries offering visa sponsorship for unskilled labour, I am willing to work, more so, will my employer pay for my visa fee's and anything concerning the visa processing?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because requests for off-site resources are generally considered out of scope on Stack Exchange. As are questions like this one where the correct answer will change rapidly. It's also much too broad a question since even "unskilled" jobs have some requirements, and guest-worker programs, when they exist, often have limitations to specific tasks, places, and times, and don't get more than short-term visas if that.

Comment: This question needs a lot more information to even answer anything. Things like which country is the OP in currently.

Comment: Almost no countries offer visas for unskilled labour, because unskilled jobs can always be done by someone already in the country.

Comment: @DJClayworth, That's incorrect. The US for instance has the H-2A Temporary Agricultural Workers visa. https://www.farmers.gov/working-with-us/h2a-visa-program However, the OP needs to be super careful. These temporary workers do not have many rights, and then they're forced to leave the country by a certain date.

Comment: I had forgotten temporary agricultural workers. But they are an entirely different category.